# "git log -m" always show both diffs

Tags: git, parsing, git-log

I'm currently writing a program that needs to read a git log-file and reconstruct the complete filetree out of it.
To support file-tracking and renames through different branches I need to see file creations and renaming on merges. For this I can use the '-m'-argument that git already provides: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt--m

-m generates a diff for both parents of a merge. This is good and exactly what I need. But now comes the problem. If the diff for one parent is empty, only one diff gets printed. The format of both diffs is exactly the same. The only way to see to which parent a diff applies is by checking the order they get printed. The first one is the one from the merge-source-parent and the second one is from the merge-target-parent. The problem is that if one of both diffs is empty I can't find out to which parent the printed diff belongs.
I use this command to generate the log:
`git log --pretty=format:'[%h] [%an] (%p) %ad %s' --date="format:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" -m --numstat --summary --parents`
Is there a way to let the git command print the headline of the diff even if the diff is empty? Or is there any other way to find out to which parent the diff belongs if only one diff gets printed?

Comment: There's no *easy* way, as far as I know. Since you have parent hashes, you can tell that a commit was a merge and that you got only partial information, and go back later and compare the trees of the commit and each of its parents, and that will tell you which parent diff(s) showed up.

Comment: Hm, building on that: add `%T` to your format so that you get each commit's tree's hash ID. Then you have the information locally. (BTW for programmatic examination I'd recommend avoiding shortened hashes. Git generally tries to make sure they're unique, but if someone missed a case of testing for uniqueness, you could get two shortened hashes that seem identical, but differ past the abbreviation point.)

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the response. I hoped that I could somehow prevent going down the tree and to check to which parent the diff belongs. But it looks like I have no choice. :/

Answer (score 0):

> But now comes the problem. If the diff for one parent is empty, only one diff gets printed. The format of both diffs is exactly the same.

No, that's not true (edit:, rather, yes, the *format* is the same, but each diff shows you which parent it's from in the header line). Notice the `(from` tag after the commit id, there's one such block for each diff.

```
$ git log -1 -m -p --merges
commit 00780c9af44409a68481c82f63a97bd18bb2593e (from 1659e49c4befea40d58fd01e6a005b49ec65fbb1)
Merge: 1659e49c4b 1ffcbaa1a5
Author: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>
Date:   Wed Jan 12 16:31:43 2022 -0800

    Merge branch 'master' into next
    
    * master:
      Last minute fixes before -rc1

diff --git a/Documentation/RelNotes/2.35.0.txt b/Documentation/RelNotes/2.35.0.txt
index 26efaf1cbc..fa5a7318a8 100644
--- a/Documentation/RelNotes/2.35.0.txt
+++ b/Documentation/RelNotes/2.35.0.txt
@@ -100,7 +100,7 @@ Performance, Internal Implementation, Development Support etc.
  * Teach and encourage first-time contributors to this project to
    state the base commit when they submit their topic.
 
- * The command line complation for "git send-email" options have been
+ * The command line completion for "git send-email" options have been
    tweaked to make it easier to keep it in sync with the command itself.
 
  * Ensure that the sparseness of the in-core index matches the
@@ -367,6 +367,13 @@ Fixes since v2.34
    it failed to restore changes to tracked ones.
    (merge 71cade5a0b en/stash-df-fix later to maint).
 
+ * Calling dynamically loaded functions on Windows has been corrected.
+   (merge 4a9b204920 ma/windows-dynload-fix later to maint).
+
+ * Some lockfile code called free() in signal-death code path, which
+   has been corrected.
+   (merge 58d4d7f1c5 ps/lockfile-cleanup-fix later to maint).
+
  * Other code cleanup, docfix, build fix, etc.
    (merge 74db416c9c cw/protocol-v2-doc-fix later to maint).
    (merge f9b2b6684d ja/doc-cleanup later to maint).
@@ -391,3 +398,5 @@ Fixes since v2.34
    (merge 999bba3e0b rs/daemon-plug-leak later to maint).
    (merge 786eb1ba39 js/l10n-mention-ngettext-early-in-readme later to maint).
    (merge 2f12b31b74 ab/makefile-msgfmt-wo-stats later to maint).
+   (merge 0517f591ca fs/gpg-unknown-key-test-fix later to maint).
+   (merge 97d6fb5a1f ma/header-dup-cleanup later to maint).

commit 00780c9af44409a68481c82f63a97bd18bb2593e (from 1ffcbaa1a5f10c9f706314d77f88de20a4a498c2)
Merge: 1659e49c4b 1ffcbaa1a5
Author: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>
Date:   Wed Jan 12 16:31:43 2022 -0800

    Merge branch 'master' into next
    
    * master:
      Last minute fixes before -rc1

diff --git a/Documentation/git-cat-file.txt b/Documentation/git-cat-file.txt
index 27b27e2b30..bef76f4dd0 100644
--- a/Documentation/git-cat-file.txt
+++ b/Documentation/git-cat-file.txt
@@ -9,8 +9,14 @@ git-cat-file - Provide content or type and size information for repository objec
 SYNOPSIS
 --------
 [verse]
-'git cat-file' (-t [--allow-unknown-type]| -s [--allow-unknown-type]| -e | -p | <type> | --textconv | --filters ) [--path=<path>] <object>
-'git cat-file' (--batch[=<format>] | --batch-check[=<format>]) [ --textconv | --filters ] [--follow-symlinks]
+'git cat-file' <type> <object>
+'git cat-file' (-e | -p) <object>
+'git cat-file' (-t | -s) [--allow-unknown-type] <object>
+'git cat-file' (--batch | --batch-check) [--batch-all-objects]
+        [--buffer] [--follow-symlinks] [--unordered]
+        [--textconv | --filters]
+'git cat-file' (--textconv | --filters)
+        [<rev>:<path|tree-ish> | --path=<path|tree-ish> <rev>]
 
 DESCRIPTION
 -----------
diff --git a/apply.c b/apply.c
index 7ffadc3b17..f66d48ba2f 100644

[ …snip… ]
```

If you did an `-s ours` merge you'll get only one diff, that's true, but the header line will still show you which parent the diff's from.